# Are there default functions for discrete uniform distributions in R?

Tags: r, distributions, uniform-distribution

Most standard distributions in R have a family of commands - pdf/pmf, cdf/cmf, quantile, random deviates (for example- dnorm, pnorm, qnorm, rnorm).

I know it's easy enough to make use of some standard commands to reproduce these functions for the discrete uniform distributions, but is there already a preferred built-in family of functions for modeling discrete uniform distributions in R that I'm unaware of?

Comment: For those still seeking an answer, I found this: purrr:: rdunif, see: https://rdrr.io/cran/purrr/man/rdunif.html

Comment: @Nnie, that does not really answer the whole question which asked for the complete family of functions whereas the one you link to only does random draws.

Comment: The complete family is available at https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/extraDistr/versions/1.8.10/topics/DiscreteUniform in the extraDistr package, apparently.

Answer (score 36):

As nico wrote, they're not implemented in R. Assuming we work in 1..k, those functions should look like:

For random generation:

```
rdu<-function(n,k) sample(1:k,n,replace=T)
```

PDF:

```
ddu<-function(x,k) ifelse(x>=1 & x<=k & round(x)==x,1/k,0)
```

CDF:

```
pdu<-function(x,k) ifelse(x<1,0,ifelse(x<=k,floor(x)/k,1))
```

Comment: Thanks. I think it would be handy to have built-in functions (with min and max paraemters ala the unif family). It's a bit ugly to have to add function definitions into scripts just to use the discrete uniform distributions the way you would use other standard distributions. The builtin functions also deal with error handling (for example - if parameters aren't integers) and are optimized for speed.

Comment: Nice answer.  And for the quantiles we can do something like qdu <- function(p, k) ifelse(p <= 0 | p > 1, return("undefined"), ceiling(p*k))

Answer (score 17):

Here is the code for the discrete uniform distribution in the range [min, max], adapted from mbq's post:

```
dunifdisc<-function(x, min=0, max=1) ifelse(x>=min & x<=max & round(x)==x, 1/(max-min+1), 0)
punifdisc<-function(q, min=0, max=1) ifelse(q<min, 0, ifelse(q>=max, 1, (floor(q)-min+1)/(max-min+1)))
qunifdisc<-function(p, min=0, max=1) floor(p*(max-min+1))
runifdisc<-function(n, min=0, max=1) sample(min:max, n, replace=T)
```

Answer (score 15):

The [CRAN Task View: Probability Distributions](http://finzi.psych.upenn.edu/views/Distributions.html) page says:

> The discrete uniform distribution can be easily obtained with the basic functions.

I guess something on the lines of this should do:

```
a <- round(runif(1000, min=0, max=100))
```

**EDIT**

As csgillespie pointed out, this is not correct...

```
a <- ceiling(runif(1000, min=0, max=100))
```

will work though (note that the example will generate values between **1** and 100, not 0 and 100)

Comment: This isn't correct for the edge cases. To see this, try running the following command: `table(round(runif(10000, min=0, max=2)))` It's clearly not discrete uniform.

Comment: @csgillespie: nicely spotted, I updated my answer :)

Comment: Couldn't you use `ceiling(runif(1000, min=-1, max=100))`?

Answer (score 0):

This function might be what you are looking for:

https://purrr.tidyverse.org/reference/rdunif.html

```
rdunif(n, b, a = 1)
```