# Distribution from which to sample integers evenly between 1 and 1000?

Tags: distributions, simulation, discrete-data

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Are there default functions for discrete uniform distributions in R?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/3930/are-there-default-functions-for-discrete-uniform-distributions-in-r)

Is there a distribution from which I can sample that can act as a relatively flat prior over a given range? I am looking for something like a uniform(0,1000), but that only returns integers.

I know how to get R to do this, e.g.

```
sample.int(1000, 5)
sample(1:1000, 5)
floor(runif(5, 1, 1000))
```

Is there a probability distribution that will do this (or get close to it, with or even without an upper bound)?

*Note* - I am not trying to simulate a variable with any 'real world' relevance beyond trying to develop a test of a statistical function that I have written, and any of the above solutions will work. But the problem made me curious.

Comment: Did you check Wikipedia? [Discrete Uniform Distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_distribution_(discrete)).

Comment: @JasonMorgan thanks. Obviously that makes sense. The functions I was looking for are in the [related question](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/3930/are-there-default-functions-for-discrete-uniform-distributions-in-r), which answers - and mostly duplicates - my question.

Comment: Sorry. I thought you were looking for an analytic definition.

Comment: There is no way to sample uniformly if there is no upper bound.

Comment: @JasonMorgan If there were some way to flatten another common discrete distribution, I would still be interested in that.

Comment: @woodchips I guess I meant more-or-less uniformly over a more-or less wide range, similar to sampling from a $N(0,100)$ - low enough precision to meet my needs.